# Prove that $\{{z \choose k}\}$ this sequence is bounded iff $Re(z) \geq -1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

If we define ${z \choose n}= \frac {z(z-1) \cdots (z-n+1)}{n!}$ then prove that $\{{z \choose k}\}$ this sequence is bounded iff $Re(z) \geq -1$ and converges iff $Re(z) > -1$.
I have proceeded in this way that if we put $z=x+iy$ then $|{z \choose n}|=\prod_{i=0}^n|1-\frac {z+1}{i}|=\prod_{k=0}^n[1-2\frac{x+1}{k}+\frac {(x+1)^2}{k^2}+\frac {y^2}{k^2}]^{\frac12}$. Now from here how can I conclude the result? Also please check my calculation.